# Mockito Problems - InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am doing a test using mockito, but I am getting this problems:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at cl.gps.tms.planifications.planification.test.PlanificationCreateTest.setUp(PlanificationCreateTest.java:68)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

...
```

The PlanificationCreateTest use the SimpleQueryBus for create a generic query where de first parameter indicates what type of object is returned, and second parameters are filters on the query.

I want stub the SimpleQueryBus class (external library) returning a null (only for now)

The SimpleQueryBus code

```
public class SimpleQueryBus implements QueryBus {

    public <T, R> R handle(Class<R> clazz, T query) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
}
```

My test code

```
public class PlanificationCreateTest {

    private QueryBus queryBus;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        queryBus = Mockito.mock(SimpleQueryBus.class);

        when(queryBus.handle(VehicleCollection.class, any(GetVehicle.class))).thenAnswer(null);

        ....
    }
}
```

**UPDATE (SOLVED):**

```
public class PlanificationCreateTest {

    private QueryBus queryBus;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        queryBus = Mockito.mock(SimpleQueryBus.class);

        // first example
        when(queryBus.handle(any(Class.class), isA(VehicleAvailable.class))).thenReturn(null);          

        // second example
        vehicle = new VehicleCollection("001", "name", "tag", "brand", "model");            
        when(queryBus.handle(any(Class.class), isA(GetVehicle.class))).thenReturn(vehicle);

        ....
    }
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This occurs because you are using `any()` along with a real parameter `VehicleCollection.class` of type `Class<VehicleCollection>`.

Change it just like below, and you should be fine:

```
 when(queryBus.handle(any(VehicleCollection.class), any(GetVehicle.class))).thenAnswer(null);
```

Mockito explains why: http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html

> If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided
>   by matchers.
>
> E.g: (example shows verification but the same applies to stubbing):
>
> ```
>     // Correct - eq() is also an argument matcher
>     verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), eq("third argument"));
>
>
>     // Incorrect - exception will be thrown because third argument is given without argument matcher.
>     verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), "third argument");
> ```

Comment: `when(queryBus.handle(any(VehicleCollection.class), any(GetVehicle.class))).thenAnswer(null);` this didn't work??

Same error?

Comment: Sorry, but my inexperience with mockito has played a trick on me (the problem was with the return value), with theReturn(null) it worked properly, but I don't understand the difference between thenAnswer and thenReturn yet...

Comment: @Hector, I think you'll find it didn't ever work.  This won't compile, because `any(VehicleCollection.class)` has type `VehicleCollection`, and you're passing it as a parameter of type `Class`.

Comment: I finally managed to fix it. I changed the above code to indicate as I did. Thanks

Comment: On the `thenAnswer()` method, you need to specify a callback method to execute and return a object. On the `thenReturn()` method, you just need to specify an returning object.

Answer (score 2):

This is also a problem for `EasyMock`

Basically whenever you use a Matcher on one argument, you need to use them on all the arguments

```
when(queryBus.handle(isA(VehicleCollection.class), any(GetVehicle.class))).thenAnswer(null);
```

Should work

I added `isA(Class)` which creates a matcher to make sure the argument type matches the given class.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but don´t compile: _italic_The method handle(Class<R>, T) in the type QueryBus is not applicable for the arguments (VehicleCollection, GetVehicle) PlanificationCreateTest.java_italic_

Answer (score 2):

Change your `when` clause to

```
when(queryBus.handle(eq(VehicleCollection.class), any(GetVehicle.class))) ....
```

If you use one matcher, then every argument must be a matcher.  And in this case, the first argument must be a matcher of type `Class<R>`.  So don't use `isA` or `any`, because they will give you type `VehicleCollection`.  Instead, you need `eq`.